# Add default value to select list in Laravel form::select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Simple question, I hope.

I need to add a default value to my select list 'Please Select', and set it to disabled.

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="" disabled>Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

My current laravel form::select is

```
{{
Form::select(
    'myselect',
    $categories,
    $myselectedcategories,
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'myselect'
    )
}}
```

How can I amend this to include the default option value?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` like this:

```
{{
Form::select(
    'myselect',
    array_merge(['' => 'Please Select'], $categories),
    $myselectedcategories,
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'myselect'
    ))
}}
```

Alternatively you can set the placeholder somewhere before the select:

```
$categories[''] = 'Please Select';
```

#### Update

To add the disabled attribute you can try this: (untested)

```
{{
Form::select(
    'myselect',
    array_merge(['' => ['label' => 'Please Select', 'disabled' => true], $categories),
    $myselectedcategories,
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'myselect'
    ))
}}
```

Comment: That works great. Thank you.  Do you know how to add disabled to this option?

Comment: `array_merge` will resort the keys, if this matters to you.

eg. `array_merge(['' => 'Please select'], [1 => 'key is 1', 0 => 'key is 0'])` returns `['' => 'Please select', 0 => 'key is 1', 1 => 'key is 0']`.

Answer (score 28):

In Laravel 5.1 you can prepend the default item if the list is a collection (result of a `Eloquent::lists()`)

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
$categories->prepend('None');
```

Comment: Way cleaner! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to the second line to be `$categories->prepend('None', 0)` to give it a key so that the ids are preserved.

Comment: when prepend is not available, we can use: `$categories = array(0 , 'None') + $categories`

Answer (score 13):

Add `'placeholder' => 'Please Select'` into the `Form::select`.

```
{!!
  Form::select(
    'myselect', 
    $categories, 
    null, 
    ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please Select'])
!!}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just put placeholder, for example:

```
[
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'id' => 'myselect',
    'placeholder' => 'None'
]
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: **Worth Noting**: It is **placeholder** in all small letters not **placeHolder** in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
$categories->prepend('None', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

For, prepending **Please Select** with empty value

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
$categories->prepend('Please Select', '');
```

This code will populate something like this ,

```
$categories[''] = 'Please Select';
$categories[0] = 'item 1',
$categories[1] = 'item 2';
```

Now you can use something like this:

```
{!! Form::select('myselect', $categories, '',['id'=>'myselect']) !!}
```

This is helpful for form validation also, like **required**.

Comment: Thanks, I used "null" with prepend and it changed all my values in dropdown. Empty Value worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Default India was select

> {{ Form::select('terms_agreement_type', [null => 'Select Control'] +
>           ['India' => 'India', 'Nepal' => 'Nepal'], 'India') }}

Answer (score 1):

You can use pluck

Controller

```
$role = Model::all();

{{ Form::select('nameselect', $role->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('default value...', ""))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i put my solution for this post. I hope can help to somebody

i use a php function to add an option to the array of the model

array_unshift($model, ['value' => '', 'name' => 'Select value']);

Answer (score 0):

i have used placeholder  and it worked for me

> {!! Form::select('supplier', $suppliers, null, ['class' =>
>   'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please Select']) !!}

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer this question's description, searching the title brought me here. The third parameter of `Form::select()` is what dictates the default selected value.

```
{!! Form::select('event_id', $events, $defaultSelectedEventId) !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Laravel 5.3**

```
{{ Form::select('role', ['' => 'Select Role'] +$roles, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```