# Fom::select in laravel empty for default

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-form

I´m trying to create a form select in laravel.

I was created perfectly, but in my view first option is `0` and one first option empty
[image]

I need to remove this `0` and option empty, but i don't know how i can do it, this is my actual code:

```
<div class="form-group row ">
        {!! Form::label('restaurant_id', trans("lang.blog_restaurant_id"),['class' => 'col-3 control-label text-right']) !!}
        <div class="col-9">
            {!! Form::select('restaurant_id', [null => null, $restaurant], null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control']) !!}
            <div class="form-text text-muted">{{ trans("lang.blog_restaurant_id_help") }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

$restaurant it's one data array for to fill my select. I read that with first option null put selected option empty, but generate a empty option and 0.

Thanks for help me.

**UPDATE**

Laravel include optgroup into Form::select that it´s triggering my `0` this it´s the problem. i need delete optgroup

```
  <select class="select2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" id="restaurant_id" name="restaurant_id" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>

    <optgroup label="0">
    
        <option value="17">Foody Lindgren, Cremin and Erdman gdfgfg fgfg fg fgfg g fggf</option>
        <option value="28">restaurante de pruebas</option>
        <option value="29">probando</option>
        <option value="30">pincho de castilla2</option>
    
    </optgroup>
```

**update 2**

getting list of restaurant:

```
$restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->pluck('name', 'id');
```

this is result in blade:

```
{"17":"Foody Lindgren, Cremin and Erdman gdfgfg fgfg fg fgfg g fggf","28":"restaurante de pruebas","29":"probando","30":"pincho de castilla2"}
```

Add toArray():

```
$restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->pluck('name', 'id');
$restaurant->toArray();
```

same result

Comment: I think this is duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892437/add-default-value-to-select-list-in-laravel-formselect/40976047)

Comment: @TansukhRathod no, because, i have a 0, i have a picture in my question that explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Add blank key and blank value like below.

```
{!! Form::select('restaurant_id', ["" => "", $restaurant], null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: same result. My problem it, that for default, in Form::select include optgroup, i updated my question to add this from web browser console

Comment: this is my question... how i can delete it. it´s for default in laravel Form::select i need only option not optgroup

Comment: Hey, I am not asking to delete your question.

Comment: Please try this. {!! Form::select('restaurant_id', $restaurant, null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control']) !!}. if this is not working then can you please show data of $restaurant variable

Comment: this not working, my $restaurant it´s a object

Comment: $restaurant variable must be an array

Comment: how i can transform my return query in array... if i do cast with array() put array['*items']... if i do toArray() nothing...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `$restaurant` is an array.
So, you'd better do something like this:

```
Form::select('restaurant_id', $restaurant, null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control'])
```

you may need a proper mapping for your `$restaurant` in your controller, depending on what you need, like adding an empty option in the beginning.

```
// in Controller
$options = ["" => "select"] + $restaurant;

// In view
Form::select('restaurant_id', $options, null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control'])
```

**update 2**

You should make sure to send the `$restaurant` as an array:

```
$restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

For adding an empty option:

```
$restaurant = ["" => "select"] + $restaurant;
```

There is also another option:
You can even add the select box manually instead of using `Form::select`.

```
<select class="select2 form-control" id="restaurant_id" name="restaurant_id">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    @foreach($restaurant as $value => $option)
    <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $option }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i added your code in my controller and my blade, and returned: Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to number

Comment: The `$restaurant` or `$options` should be an array. So, if it is a collection, you can make sure you provide an array by adding `$restaurant->toArray()`.

Comment: thaks for your help, i was updated my question with update 2 and add my function controller where i get my restaurant and my result. i was trayed to add toArray() i´m getting same result

Comment: try `$restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();`

Comment: it´s ok your code. but i´m traying with things and i can show that it´s a multidimensional array. if i do ["0" => $restaurant][0] i have my data without label '0' but also i need option empty and here i don´t know how i can to do